# Cannot get details of data from product table that are added to wishlist table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want the details of product that are added to wishlist table. I'm getting the data from wishlist table but i want to establish relation from product and user model also so that i can get the details of the product. My table Structure is :

> Wishlists table:

```
id | product_id | user_id
```

> products table :

```
id | name | price
```

> users table :

```
id  | first_name  | last_name | contact
```

> Wishlist Model :

```
public function user(){
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function product(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

> Product Model :

```
public function wishlist(){
    return $this->hasMany(Wishlist::class);
 }

 public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

> Users Model :

```
public function wishlist(){
    return $this->hasMany(Wishlist::class);
 }
```

I'm getting data from wishlist table through this code but can't get data from product table :

```
return Wishlist::with('product')->where('user_id', auth()->id())->get();
```

product relation is returning null

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use a [Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship. In this case, you don't need the `Wishlist` model.

**Product.php**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'wishlists');
}
```

**User.php**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'wishlists');
}
```

Then you can get the user's wishlist like this:

```
auth()->user()->products;
```

Comment: I have used this code: $wishlist  = $this->wishlistRepository->listWishlist(); but product data is empty.

Comment: this is the code of listWishlist : $this->model->with('product')->where('user_id', auth()->id())->get();